# Angularjs - $http promise error handling

Tags: http, angularjs, error-handling

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to make a $http call with the .then function insted .sucssess and .error. But although i change the url of the request to a non existing one, it is always executing the succes handler:

```
$http.get('data/myjson.json').then(onSuccess, onError);

onSuccess(data){};
onError(data){};
```

Also, the data parameter has a status of 404, indicating the failure, but the onError got never execute.

some body can explain how this really work?

thanks!

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using angular 1.0.7.

Answer (score 12):

This code works for me:

```
$http.get('data/myjson.json').then(onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(data) {
}
function onError(data) {
}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, thanks for your answer. The onError function, got execute when you use a wrong url for the request? In case of success, my code works, the problem is error handling

Comment: What do you mean with error handling? What response do you get to handle errors on?

Comment: I mean, when i try tu put a wrong url (for example dataaaa/myjson.com), i want the onError to be executed, but the onSucces is being executed instead

Comment: If i'm correct, this should work as $http.get('data/myjson.json').succes().error, should it?

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn Good work. It works for me..  (upvote)

Answer (score 2):

```
  $http.get(url).then(onSuccess, onerror);   
   function onSuccess(response) {
    //Success message here...
                                    }
    function onerror(data) {

                if(data.status==404) {
                    alert('Invalid URl')
                            return;
                }

    }
```

Just try this one ...

Answer (score 1):

Both way can be use for ng promise error handling:-

**First:**

```
$http.get('data/myjson.json')
.success( successHandler )
.error( errorHandler )

function successHandler(data) {
}
function errorHandler(data) {
}
```

***Second:***

```
$http.get('data/myjson.json').then(successHandler, errorHandler);

function successHandler(data) {
}
function errorHandler(data) {
}
```